# Strange memory only when using copy

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a class named `SomeClass`. in its `init` I have a lot of lines like:

```
SomeProperty_ = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithSomething];
```

While the properties are declared as

```
@property(retain) SomeObject *SomeProperty;
```

and defined as

```
@synthesize SomeProperty = SomeProperty_;
```

When I allocate objects of `SomeClass` and later release them, everything works fine and there are no memory leaks. However, when I copy an object of `SomeClass` and later release it, all the lines like

```
SomeProperty_ = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithSomething];
```

are marked as a memory leak in Instruments. this is also correct as I get memory warning and later crash if I use this a lot.
However if I make a method named `dealloc` like:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.SomeProperty = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Everything is fine with copies as well and no memory warning or leaks.
I think this is because of my `copy` implementation:

```
-(id)copy
{
    SomeClass *copy = [[SomeClass alloc] init];

    copy.SomeProperty.somePOD = self.SomeProperty.somePOD;

    return copy;
}
```

Where is the problem? what can I do to resolve it without the custom `dealloc`?

Comment: Uh, you do know that you're clobbering the iOS `copy` method, don't you?

Comment: @Abizern: I'm what? I know there is a meaning to copy method in objective-c, but if I need a custom implementation of copy, can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol

Answer (score 0):

The first things I can think of is:

How your `somePOD` is set as far as @property(???)

And when you say :
"However, when I copy an object of SomeClass and later release it, all the lines like

`SomeProperty_ = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithSomething];`
are marked as a memory leak in Instruments. this is also correct as I get memory warning and later crash if I use this a lot."

You are referring to call made in your `init` method?
Because if your not, you are bypassing a setter and the object that was in that variable before this assignment will leak.

Answer (score 0):

You must either use a custom dealloc method or start using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

When you call `[[SomeObject alloc] init...]`, you get ownership of the new object, so you must release the object when you are done with it.  Setting `self.SomeProperty` to nil does the release because you declare the property with the retain attribute.

You do this in your dealloc method if you want to own the SomeObject object until your SomeClass object dies.  If you use ARC, it will generate the dealloc method for you.